# Automation Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 using Python(pywinauto)

Tags: windows, python-2.7, automation, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am creating **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio** **Automation tool using python**. The problem is I can't select the **Child_tree**(Northwind) database It's selecting the **Parent_tree**(Databases). I need to do much more, clicking the child_tree(Northwind) right click option (Ex. Tasks-> backup). Help me to do the best automation code.
Thanks in Advance.

```
import pywinauto
import socket
import binascii
host = socket.gethostname()   #Getting system host name
n2 = int('0b111000001100001011100110111001101110111011011110111001001100100', 2) #password
n1 = int('0b111010101110011011001010111001001101110011000010110110101100101', 2) # username
n  = int('0b1110011011001010111001001110110011001010111001001101110011000010110110101100101', 2) #servername av
if (host == "systemhostXXX" or host == "systemhostyyy"): # checking the host name 
     try:
        pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()
        path = pwa_app.start_(r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/Ssms.exe") #Opening the .exe file

        print("Status: Application Launched successfully!!")
    except:
            print("Error: Applicatin Launching Error!!")
    try:
```

pwa_app.ConnecttoServer.ComboBox1.Select("Database Engine")   #Selecting the combobox value 
    pwa_app.ConnecttoServer.edit1.SetText(binascii.unhexlify('%x' % n))
    pwa_app.ConnecttoServer.ComboBox3.Select("SQL Server Authentication")
    pwa_app.ConnecttoServer.edit2.SetText(binascii.unhexlify('%x' % n1))   # convert binary into string
    pwa_app.ConnecttoServer.edit3.SetText(binascii.unhexlify('%x' % n2))
    print("Status: Log-in Process!!")
    pwa_app.ConnecttoServer.Connect.Click()
except:
    print("Error: Log-In Failed!!Please Relaunch!")

try:
    pwa_app.ConnecttoServer.Ok.Click()  #Button click (OK)
    pwa_app.ConnecttoServer.Cancel.Click()
    print("Error: Restoration going-on!!")
except:
    print("Status: Log-in Success!!")

    try:
        w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio', class_name='wndclass_desked_gsk')[0]
        window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
        ctrl = window['TreeView']  
        ctrl.GetItem([u'SQL Server 8.0.2039']).Click() 
        ctrl.GetItem([u'SQL Server 8.0.2039', u'Databases', u'Northwind']).Click() #Selecting the database

    except:
        print("Database selection failed !!")

else:
     print 'Dear', host,'You are not Authorized to Run this program\n'

Comment: It's not clear where your script is failing. Please mark concrete line which fails or what functionality do you need after some line.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Vasily Ryabov " ctrl.GetItem([u'SQL Server 8.0.2039', u'Databases', u'Northwind']).Click()  #Selecting the database "- In this line the Northwind is not selecting instead of that the code is selecting the databases option only. Also I need(code) to do the further operation of the restoration (Auto clicking).

Comment: OK, can you remove try-except handling and provide Exception output? Please edit your question.

Comment: Your exception handler prints that only `Database selection failed`. Please add `import traceback; traceback.print_exc()` in the `except:` block. What is printed after that?

Comment: `except Exception as exc:` is also useful if you `print(exc)` as well.

Comment: I don't receive notifications about your post editing. Please post a comment if you edited the post and want faster reaction. Thanks!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
I am getting this error:   File "C:\Python27\msdb.py", line 57, in <module>
    w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio', class_name='wndclass_desked_gsk')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range. #kindly provide the solution also the database selection is not working

Comment: OK, as I understand this line fails: `w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio', class_name='wndclass_desked_gsk')[0]`. Probably the window is not opened yet. So you need to add waiting the window. Am I right?

Comment: I can't get you. Please explain briefly. Thanks

Comment: I tried to explain it in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand in comments, you need waiting until main window is open after login.

```
window = pwa_app.Window_(title=u'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio', class_name='wndclass_desked_gsk')
window.Wait('ready', timeout=20) # default timeout is 5 sec. if any
ctrl = window['TreeView']
ctrl.GetItem([u'SQL Server 8.0.2039']).Click() 
ctrl.GetItem([u'SQL Server 8.0.2039', u'Databases', u'Northwind']).Click() #Selecting the database
```

Please check how it works.

**EDIT**:

It seems you generated the code for `'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio'` window using SWAPY. It means that the window was already open.

But in automated workflow `Log-in` is quite long operation (may take up to 10 seconds I believe). So when you clicked "Connect" button, `'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio'` is not open yet. You may see some progress window or even nothing for a few seconds.

Function `find_windows` doesn't wait while the window appears on the screen. It just finds the window at that moment. So when you execute line

```
window = pwa_app.Window_(title=u'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio', class_name='wndclass_desked_gsk')
```

**WindowSpecification** object is created (`window` variable). `ctrl = window['TreeView']` is also WindowSpecification object. They are just descriptions and are not connected with real window/control. But the following statement

```
ctrl.GetItem([u'SQL Server 8.0.2039']).Click()
```

is equivalent to

```
ctrl.WrapperObject().GetItem([u'SQL Server 8.0.2039']).Click()
```

or

```
ctrl.Wait('visible').GetItem([u'SQL Server 8.0.2039']).Click()
```

pywinauto hides `WrapperObject()` call using power of Python. So it's called automatically. Default timeout is 5 seconds in this case. It might be insufficient for long time operations like Log-in. That's why I suggest calling `Wait('ready', timeout=20)` explicitly. `'ready'` means `'exists visible enabled'` using logical `AND`.